# How do I insert an HTML page using PHP?

Tags: php, html, insert, external

I wanted to know, is there any way to insert an HTML page into PHP without using the include function? I do not want to use an external html file, I want to write the html coding directly into the php coding.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Interleave it:

```
<?php

// Some php code.

?>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <?php /* More php code. */ ?>
    <p>Blah!</a>
  </body>
</html>
<?php /* Even more php. */ ?>
```

From a best practices point of view, though, avoid doing this - having business logic (PHP) and presentation (HTML) in the same place makes maintaining harder.

**EDIT:** To address your comment. You can either do it the same way, or use `echo`:

```
<?php if (x == 5) { ?>
  <p>Blah!</a>
<?php } else {
  echo '<p>Bleh</p>';
} ?>
```

Comment: I need it to be included in the php coding though. In an if statement. I need it to be more like 
<?PHP 
if(var=true){
<html>
  <title>YAY</title>
</html>
}

Comment: Using Max's example you can easily achieve what you are further asking for in your comment....

Comment: @Sean Booth: The *alternative syntax for control statements* is much easier to read:http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: Mixing "normal" HTML output and echoing HTML makes it even harder to read the code. Your updated example is not very good.

Comment: @Felix: There's a clear note about what you **should** do. The example simply shows what you **can** do.

Comment: @Felix: Thank you so much! That worked PERFECTLY, I figured there was a pretty simple way, I am still just learnign PHP (obviously)

Comment: Regarding your edit: **PLEASE AVOID MIXING PHP AND HTML LIKE THIS!** I have 2000 lines of code like this, written by someone else. It is absolutely unreadable and not even easy to remove, while maintain the functionality. PLEASE AVOID! (downvote)

Answer (score 0):

It is very bad habit to mix HTML and PHP (for more than just output control), but here you go:

```
$html = "<div>This is HTML</div>"
echo $html;
```

or [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax:

```
$html = <<<EOF
<div>
    <p>
        Some longer HTML
    </p>
</div>
EOF;
echo $html;
```

or using [alternative syntax for control statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) if the output depends on some condition (or if you loop through an array etc.)(which is far better than building HTML with strings):

```
<?php if($foo): ?>

    <div> Some HTML output </div>

<?php else: ?>

    <div> Some other HTML </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

or just

```
<?php //PHP here ?>

<div>HTML</div>

<?php //more PHP ?>

<div>more HTML</div>

<?php //even more PHP ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to include snippets of HTML based on conditions, you can interleave code like this. In this case it's convenient to use the [alternative syntax for loop controls](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

```
<?php if ( $var ): ?>
<html>
<title>YAY</title> 
</html>
<?php endif; ?>
```

so the code is clearer to read and you retain HTML syntax coloring (if your editor supports it).